# How to pass the password as parameter in Powershell script

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, parameters, 7zip

I've got the following parameter setup and trying to pass it into the 7zip password as the script shows. The Reason i've setup the parameter is I need passto contain the current month plus the rest of the password.

Script

```
$Password = $MonthFull+$year+"#Test"

Start-job -scriptblock {
    param($p_output_zip_file, $p_exported_files)
    Set-Alias SZ "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" 
    **SZ a $p_output_zip_file $p_exported_files -sdel -p'Jun2020#Test'** -- I need this to pick up the current month plus the rest of the password

} -name "Compress_File" -ArgumentList "$output_zip_file","$exported_files" | Out-Null
```

Thanks

Comment: `'Jun2020#Test'` --> `('{0:MMMyyyy}{1}' -f (Get-Date), '#Test')`

Comment: Thanks for this, I can see that this will set the password as I wanted but 7zip comes back with wrong password when extracting.

Comment: You may need to surround the constructed password with single quotes (like you did with the hardcoded example). Cannot test now because I'm on mobile.

Comment: This fixed it $('-p' + ('{0:MMMyyyy}{1}' -f (Get-Date), '#Test'))

Answer (score 0):

```
$('-p' + ('{0:MMMyyyy}{1}' -f (Get-Date), '#Test'))
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.